# Is there any way to debug macros?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging

I got a legacy application with a bunch of global singletons defined as macroses in precompiled headers:

```
#define myGlobalState [MyGlobalState getInstance]
#define settingsManager [SettingsManager getInstance]
```

Is there any way I could access these singletons from inside a debugger repl?

Comment: Those macros look wrong.  What if you want to assign a property of `myGlobalState`?  It's much more convenient without the `=` in there.  WRT debugging, can't you put breakpoints on those `getInstance` methods?

Comment: I've misspelled the example, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @trojanfoe I could, but it won't help since these singletons have mutable state.

Comment: Actually, I could do something like `[[MyGlobalState getInstance] someProperty]`, but it's not particulary convinient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way I could access these singletons from inside a
>   debugger repl?

So, first, they aren't singletons.  They are expressions that get evaluated every time the macro is used.   Unfortunate, that.

Secondly, prefixed with `get`?  That's a sure sign that the codebase was created by someone not familiar with Objective-C and an indication that there'll likely be other significant problems with the design.

Finally, the easiest solution -- but it changes behavior -- is to create actual global variables called `myGlobalState` and `settingsManager`, set them in some initialization phase of the app or library, and get rid of the `#define` altogether.  That would make them available in the debugger and would likely render a behavior a lot closer to what the original author meant.

**Alternatively** (and, arguably, a better solution), would be to rename the `get` methods to `sharedInstance` (as they should be), then find and replace all instances of `myGlobalState` with `[MyGlobalState sharedInstance]` and do away with the macro entirely.

For the former, you can use the global directly in the debugger.  For the latter, you'd have to evaluate `[MyGlobalState sharedInstance]` in the debugger, but that isn't a big deal.

(And, yeah, you could just evaluate `[MyGlobalState getGlobalState]` in the debugger, leave all the mis-named stuff alone and call it a day.)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, it covers all the areas I need to investigate.